# Get information from Gradle eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, buildship

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin. 
In my plugin I run a Gradle task.

The Gradle is executed when the user clicks on a button.

I want to let the user to choose whether he want to use the Gradle wrapper, local Gradle installation directory or a specific Gradle version.

I noticed that in Eclipse preferences under Gradle, there is an option to choose between each one of them. I want to read this configuration from my plugin. Does somebody knows how to read this configuration?

Thanks!

[image: eclipse preferences]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who encounter this issue, I found the answer myself:

```
IPreferencesService service = Platform.getPreferencesService();
service.getString("org.eclipse.buildship.core", "gradle.distribution", "", null)
```

This returns, for example:

```
GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION(WRAPPER)

or

GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION(VERSION(6.4))

...
```